# how to pass cookies to a new activity?

Tags: android

Say i have one activity that gets a cookie and then starts a new activity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, act2.class);
this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

But how do I pass that cookie to the new activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to send data from one Activity to another Activity.

eg.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, act2.class);
myIntent.putExtra("CookieKey",cookieValue);
this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

and In other activity, you can get this extras using

```
String cookie=getIntent().getStringExtra("CookieKey");
```

or in a more clear way you can use :

```
  Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();

  if(bundle!=null)
  {
        if(bundle.contains("CookieKey")){

             String cookie=bundle.getString("CookieKey");
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, to make cookieValue , do I just do MyCookie.toString() ?

Comment: Also how do I later turn that string back into a cookie again? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Intent.putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) to pass data between two activities.